# flutter command is not working in linux 14, it shows command not found, but it is already in path

Tags: flutter

Flutter command not found 
i tried adding flutter path, and it added to my path

```
/home/shameer/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/shameer/.local/bin/aws:/home/shameer/.local/bin/python:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle:/home/shameer/Android/Sdk/emulator:/home/shameer/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/shameer/Android/Sdk/tools/bin:/home/shameer/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/shameer/.local/bin/aws:/home/shameer/.composer/vendor/bin:/home/Flutter/flutter/bin
```

but still command not found
please help me to solve this issue.. thanks

Comment: where do you have flutter installed? what is its `bin` folder?

Comment: i installed in a folder named Flutter in my home directory

Comment: so there is no `/home/shameer/Flutter/bin` in your path

Comment: Thank you.. that was mistake... i just solved it,  Thank you

Comment: sure, your welcome